Deleting single GSI out of many using Amplify CLI toolkit
I wanted to delete single GSI from 4 GSIs I had in a project.
But the Amplify CLI toolkit only gave option to delete all GSIs. When I ran amplify update storage, the CLI toolkit asked following option in the flow:
Do you want to keep existing global secondary indexes created on your table? (Y/n) · no
Selecting "No" to this option removes all the GSI at once.
(And there is no option to select and remove single GSI in amplify cli version 12.10.3)
When I selected "no" to above option and tried to push the changes to server, I got following error:
 The following resources failed to deploy:
Resource Name: DynamoDBTable (AWS::DynamoDB::Table)
Event Type: update
Reason: Resource handler returned message: "Cannot perform more than one GSI creation or deletion in a single update" (RequestToken: fcd558ca-1d24-4590-d3b1-d5f57c0cc17f, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

I tried to find a way to remove only selected GSI, but I did not find any such option.

I managed to delete a single GSI by going into the amplify/backend/storage/<dynamodbresourcename>/cli-inputs.json file, which had structure similar to the below:
{
  "resourceName": "dbname",
  "tableName": "dbnane",
  "partitionKey": {
    "fieldName": "pk",
    "fieldType": "string"
  },
  "sortKey": {
    "fieldName": "sk",
    "fieldType": "string"
  },
  "gsi": [
    {
      "name": "gs1",
      "partitionKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs1pk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      },
      "sortKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs1sk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "gs2",
      "partitionKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs2pk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      },
      "sortKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs2sk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "gs3",
      "partitionKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs3pk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      },
      "sortKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs3sk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      }
    }
  ],
  "triggerFunctions": []
}

Then I simply removed the entry from gsi array for the GSI that I wanted to remove. For example, if I wanted to remove gs3, I removed that entry from gsi arrey, after which the json looked like following:
{
  "resourceName": "dbname",
  "tableName": "dbname",
  "partitionKey": {
    "fieldName": "pk",
    "fieldType": "string"
  },
  "sortKey": {
    "fieldName": "sk",
    "fieldType": "string"
  },
  "gsi": [
    {
      "name": "gs1",
      "partitionKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs1pk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      },
      "sortKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs1sk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "gs2",
      "partitionKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs2pk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      },
      "sortKey": {
        "fieldName": "gs2sk",
        "fieldType": "string"
      }
    }
  ],
  "triggerFunctions": []
}

And then ran the command amplify push storage.
I hope this helps someone.
